# ATAC seq density calculation

Tags: atac-seq

This paper [Fig2b](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-03856-y/figures/2)

> b Changes of chromatin accessibility in AMD (n = 14) relative to
> normal (n = 11) in all retina samples. Each dot represents one
> ATAC-Seq peak. Blue line in the left panel indicates average fold
> changes of peaks with the same ATAC-Seq intensity. **The percentage of
> reduced peaks is shown under the density curve in the right panel.**

How is the density calculated or what is being shown there? average ATAC seq signal or Fold change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not referring to density of reads. It is the density of the fold change, the y variable in the plot to left of Fig2b. It tells you the distribution of the foldchange and 92% of the fold change is <0.

See [this page for more details on density and histograms](https://www.statmethods.net/graphs/density.html)

Suppose your data is something like this (purely making this up):

```
set.seed(555)
fc = rnorm(1000,-0.5,2)
averATAC = -0.5*(fc - 0.5)^2 + 0.2*fc + 3  + rnorm(100,25,10)
```

You fit a density to it and you get the plot:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(averATAC,fc)
plot(dens$y,dens$x,xlab = "density",ylab="fc")
```

[image]

Comment: your answers are part of my phd work I mean those example which helps me to express my solution

Comment: how is the percentage being calculated from the density?

Comment: I think it's an overkill, but you can do ```sum(dens$y[dens$x<0])/sum(den$y)```

Comment: "overkill" i will go for it

Answer (score 0):

Just count the number of reads overlapping an ATAC-seq peak and divide it by the length of the peak gives you the read density. Each dot is a fold change, but to calculate fold change, average density from all the samples are taken, that is what the "average" is referring to.

Comment: my query is about the 92.3 % density what does it represent ? The fold change or the average ?

Comment: I see, it's the proportion of fold change falls below 0 on the y axis of the plot on the left

Comment: so is that the negative fold change they plotted?

Comment: it is a density plot of fold changes, not the density of the reads.